# Потокобезопасная коллекция с#

Tags: c#, lock

Привет. Искал инфу про потокобезопасную коллекцию и почти везде такой код:

Добавление в коллекцию

```
public void Add(int value)
{
    lock(sync)
    {         
        Add(value);
    }
}
```

тут sync это

```
private object sync = new object();
```

Я вставил себе.

```
public void Add(TkeyId keyId, TkeyName keyName, Tvalue value)
{
    lock(sync)
    {
        if (this.Where(g => g.Key.Name.Equals(keyName) && g.Key.Id.Equals(keyId)).Count() > 0)
            return;
        this.Add(new UserKey<TkeyId, TkeyName>(keyId, keyName), value);
    }
}
```

Так вот вопрос в чем прикол.Как он блокирует за счет чего.
Простым языком объясните

Comment: Ну как бы lock именно для этого и нужен... Блокирует через Monitor.

Comment: StackOverflowException?

Comment: @VladD, нет, у него вызывается метод с другой сигнатурой. полагаю, оно работает. Хотя первый пример неудачный.

Comment: @VladD возможно, там перегруженые `Add`

Comment: нет у меня не вылетат

Comment: да перегруженный Add

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Конструкция `lock` гарантирует следующее: два блока

```
lock (p)
{
    // тут содержимое блока
}
```

бегущие в разных потоках, никогда не будут выполнены одновременно, если объект `p` один и тот же.* Если один поток находится внутри `lock`, то другой будет ждать окончания выполнения этого блока. В этом и состоит суть блокировки.

Как именно технически это реализуется, не так уж и важно. В C# `lock` вызывает конструкцию `Monitor.Enter`, а она, в свою очередь, внутри кода BCL реализует функциональность, подобную `CRITICAL_SECTION` [самостоятельно](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/3a24095610ecaba62495740bf8319ad467af4997/src/vm/syncblk.h#L179), используя короткий [холостой цикл](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/8cc7e35dd0a625a3b883703387291739a148e8c8/src/vm/amd64/JitHelpers_InlineGetThread.asm#L494) (spin wait) и [системные примитивы синхронизации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx). На других системах, разумеется, используются другие синхронизационные функции ОС. Как именно работают эти функции — внутренняя подробность устройства ОС (завязанная, надо думать, на системный планировщик потоков).

Главное — знать, что внутрь `lock`'а на *один и тот же объект* два потока проникнуть не могут.

---

*Также она гарантирует нужные memory barrier'ы для многопоточного сценария, но это неважно в контексте данного обсуждения.

Comment: Вообще-то EnterCriticalSection сама крутить спин-лок умеет, нет смысла избегать ее вызова.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, спин-ожидание в исходниках я нашёл, теперь ищу EnterCriticalSection (может, вместо неё что-то другое?)

Comment: Если в коде отдельное спин-ожидание - то дальше должен быть мьютекс. Это ж классическая реализация критической секции, вряд ли создатели .NET стали придумывать что-то принципиально новое.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Более-менее нашёл. Они таки заимплементировали мьютекс руками на основе `CreateEvent`. Вот вроде бы центральный класс: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/3a24095610ecaba62495740bf8319ad467af4997/src/vm/syncblk.h#L179

Comment: После вашей правки второй комментарий оказался ни к чему не привязан: либо его нужно удалить, либо правильно привязать.

Comment: @AK: И правда! Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 3):

Оператор `lock (sync) { ... }` будет транслирован в следующую конструкцию (.NET >= 4):

```
// Флаг успешной блокировки
bool acquiredLock = false;

try
{ 
    // Захватываем блокировку для sync
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject, ref acquiredLock);

    // Потокобезопасный код

}
finally
{
    // Освобождаем блокировку для sync если блокировка была выполнена
    if (acquiredLock)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
```

Когда потоком вызывается метод `Monitor.Enter` то участок кода будет заблокирован для доступа других потоков, вплоть до того момента, когда поток не вызовет метод `Monitor.Exit`.

Comment: Начиная с .NET 4, используется другая перегрузка `Monitor.Enter`, а сам вызов помещается внутрь блока `try`.

Comment: Вы правы, (IL мне выплюнул следующий вызов – void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object, bool&)) сейчас дополню ответ